# add input row at the beginning ui5

Tags: sapui5

I'm having problems concerning adding a row with input field to add item to the table. I'm trying to use [this example](http://output.jsbin.com/pewodo)

```
addEntry : function(oEvent) {
var path = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getPath();
var obj = {
  fname: null,
  lname: null, 
  desc: null,
  createNew: false,
  removeNew: false,
  saveNew: true
};

var oModel = this.getView().getModel();

oModel.setProperty(path, obj);
```

},

The only difference that i want is for the row to be visible from the start (without the `+` icon) so that the user can directly add fields and when <kbd>OK</kbd> is clicked, a new row needs to be added.

Thank you

Comment: can u be more clear about requirment?

Comment: what i mean is  at first the table is empty ,a row is displayed containing 3 input fields when i write something and click ok the table is updated and another row is added but always the "fields" row always exisit to add items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `addEntry()` function as it is just triggering from the Add Icon and instead create the object on your `onInit()` function.

It will look like this:

```
    onInit : function() {
        var dummyData = [{"fname": "",
          "lname": "", 
          "desc": "",
          "removeNew": false,
          "saveNew": true}];

        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({data : dummyData});
        this.getView().setModel(oModel);   
   }
```

When you click on the save button, the `saveEntry()` function will be triggered and the new entry will be pushed to the model.

A new form will show up by calling the `addEmptyObject()` function at the end of it.

Here is a working example:
https://jsbin.com/wutefaz/edit?html,js,output